# Neo4j -shortest path where intermediate nodes have a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use Neo4j to find the shortest path where all of the intermediate nodes in the path have a certain relationship

Currently I have Locations, Items, and a Character
The relationships are as follows

(:Character)-[:LOCATED_AT]->(:Location) 
(:Item)-[:LOCATED_AT]->(:Location)
and sometimes 
(:character)-[:HAS_BEEN]->(:Location)

So I want to get the shortest path from where a character is located to where an item is located via all the places the character has been

Here is what I have come up with no success

```
match (i:Item {name: "Fiels"})-[:LOCATED_AT]->(desitnation:Location),        
    (c:Character {mainCharacter: true})-[:LOCATED_AT]->(current:Location),
    p= shortestPath((current)-[:CONNECTED_TO*]->(desitnation))
where all (x in nodes(p) where (c)-[:HAS_BEEN]->(x) )
return p;
```

The result returns no paths (when several are possible)

Comment: Forgot to mention, Locations can be [:CONNECTED_TO] other locations

Comment: Found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752500/find-shortest-path-between-2-nodes-using-a-node-property-filter